# What are Rulesets and RulesFile in Firestore securityRules? Why do we have multiple Rulesets deployed?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to simplify our firestore security rules and their deployment in different environments (prod / dev / test). I came across the recently added https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.securityRules.html which looked like it would be very helpful to me, as I can programmatically create and deploy rules. However the concept of `Ruleset` and `RulesFile` is very confusing.

In particular, what does it mean to have multiple `Ruleset`s deployed? I never knew this, but when I run `admin.securityRules().listRulesetMetadata()`, I see a list of over 100 such rulesets. Is it to support rollbacks? If so, how could one do that? Is the latest deployed `Ruleset` the one which is always enforced and it overrides everything from past? What is `RulesFile` then? Is there a case where there isn't a one to one mapping between RulesFile and Ruleset?

Some clarifications on these would be very helpful in determining if this is the correct solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you change your security rules, you're indeed creating a new `Ruleset`. The latest deployed `Ruleset` is active.

So when you do a rollback to an older set of rules, Firebase reads that `Ruleset` and redeploys it.

Currently there is only one `RulesFile` per `Ruleset` at least as far as the main API surfaces go (CLI, Console). This may (and very likely will) change in the future, to allow more common powerful conventions (think include files, and standard libraries) to also be applied to security rules.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response!